# Is it ok to use "is it" to emphasize?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it ok to use "is it" to emphasize?
Like in the sentence:
"A meal like that may be pricey, but boy, ***is it*** delectable."

Many thanks!

Comment: The emphatic usage arguably requires 'boy' (or equivalent) as well as the inversion.

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun *it* alone is not asserting itself in some uncharacteristically bold fashion, but the entire construction in which an exclamation is followed by a subject-finite verb inversion.

Unfortunately, although I readily found a [list of 18 uses of S-V inversion in English](http://www.testmagic.com/Knowledge_Base/lists/grammar/inversion.htm) and checked commonly consulted resources such as the relevant Wikipedia articles, this particular usage is not listed. Perhaps someone else will have better luck.

Instead, here are some real life examples, questionable punctuation and all, that illustrate this common construction:

> Boston Tea Party Ships & Museum: [Wow, was that boring!!!](https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/ShowUserReviews-g60745-d103645-r500537294-Boston_Tea_Party_Ships_Museum-Boston_Massachusetts.html)
>
> Haleakala Crater: Beautiful sunrise experience, but [man is it cold](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g143033-d103255-r46888083-Haleakala_Crater-Haleakala_National_Park_Maui_Hawaii.html).
>
> The caramel apple cider at @atlantiscoffee might put you into a sugar coma but [omg is it worth it](http://www.withthelocals.co/regina-canada-1/)
>
> BTW, I really wanted a Santa Cruz Blur to customize but [hell is it ever expensive](http://www.mtbr.com/product/bikes/xc-suspensio/khs/xc-604.html)...
>
> [OMG would I ever love](https://www.facebook.com/KraftFoods/posts/463020741344) for the weiner mobile to come to my town.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very idiomatic. This usage enables the speaker to emphasise  the difference between two observations.

*"He may look happy now **but** ...* roll eyes / suck in breath / exclaim (boy!/geez!/hell! etc) ***was he*** angry at the time."  (i.e. then he was angry, now he is happy).

*"She may be a teacher **but** ...* roll eyes / suck in breath / exclaim (boy!/geez!/hell! etc) ***is she*** short-tempered." (i.e. teachers, typically, are patient; she isn't at all).